# Javascript: How to test JSONP on localhost

Tags: javascript, jsonp

Here is the way I test JSONP: I run XAMPP, and in folder htdocs I create a javascript folder . I create `json1.json` file contain some data to process.

After that, I run this html file locally, and it will call a function in "other machine" (in this case is `localhost`)

Here is my code in this problem :

```
<head>
    <script>
            function updateSales(sales) {
                alert('test jsonp');
                // real code here
                }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JSONP Example</h1>
        <script src="http://localhost:85/javascript/json1.json?callback=updateSales"></script>
    </body>
```

But when I run, nothing happen. But if change to other real json on the internet, it will work. It means change line :

```
<script src="http://localhost:85/javascript/json1.json?callback=updateSales"></script>
```

to line:

```
<script src="http://gumball.wickedlysmart.com/?callback=updateSales"></script>
```

It will work smoothly.

So, I don't know how to test `JSONP` by using localhost, please help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP is generated on the server's side. The server fetches your data, encodes it as JSON and then wrap a function call around it.

So in your case you can either modify your `.json` file the following way:

```
updateSales( { /* your data */ } );
```

This, however, would have a hardcoded call back method, so it wont react on changes you do at retrieving it.

The other way is to write a small PHP wrapper (or use whatever else you like) and add the function around the JSON, before sending it back to the client.

```
<?php

  $json = file( "path/to/your/json" );

  echo $_GET['callback'], '(', implode( '', $json ), ');';

?>
```

(The later code is by no means for any productive use, but only for local testing!)