# Doesnt ajax jonp should work for No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, maps, leaflet

I have this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/j3Lo24hL/4/

how come i don't see the leaflet map?

when I run locally I see the map.

in addition when I try to click the `"submit button"`
I get this error.

Is there any way to make it work from `localhost`?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.waze.com/he/livemap?zoom=17&lat=51.52615424940099&lon=-0.090293…&to_lat=51.48982763805729&to_lon=-0.06797790527343749&at_req=0&at_text=Now. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
mainMap_beta.html:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://www.waze.com/he/livemap?zoom=17&lat=51.52615424940099&lon=-0.090293…797790527343749&at_req=0&at_text=Now&callback=jsonCallback&_=1454850893082' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: maybe start with fixing the `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in your fiddle

Comment: Yes, that's the beginning. Next, what was said about cross access between HTTP and HTTPS is denied, use http://jsfiddle.net/j3Lo24hL/4/ instead of https:// if your script is on http://

Comment: how do i see this error, that's my first problem. How can I inspect an error in jsFiddle?

Comment: You should try to narrow your jsFiddle down to just the ajax part that is the main cause of the error.
Getting `missing )` mixed http & https, and markers is an empty array so that fails to

Comment: It dosen't seem like your request url is a executable javascript as it's a html page... Are you trying to scrape it?

Comment: Think this solves some of the problems: http://jsfiddle.net/g5y1jbqy/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another cause is that You have an error in the 'datatype' because you declare 'jsonp' and the request is an 'text/html'.

See the final error text: " because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled".

Comment: btw, why I dont see the map?

Comment: so how can i fix this?

Comment: See where??? . . . the success function only have: function(json) {console.dir(json.sites);}

Comment: in the js fiddle example I gave

Comment: @EladBenda you need to set a height value on #map

Answer (score 0):

jsonp is not compatible with CORS in a sense that it doesn't need CORS, it is a kind of a "hack" that was made to make it possible to make cross-domain json requests.

The problem is that jsonp is incompatible with `async: false`

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation.

(From: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have JSONP callback on the local host and need to handle it properly. Good example is at [Javascript: How to test JSONP on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064572/javascript-how-to-test-jsonp-on-localhost)